# Breaking a complex query into temporary tables in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a personal proyect for academic books. I have some tables with +30.000 rows each for works, editions, authors and so on. All the information of the books —genres, subjects, authors, publishers, etc— is spread over a lot of tables with different types of relations.

I have a query for the main page that works, but the site takes six seconds to load. A lot of time… I was wondering which would be the proper approach for obtaining all the data I need with temporary tables.

What I want to do now is to join the temporary table _work with the related data of another table, say «genre». But the relationship between «work» and «genre» is done with the temporary table «work_has_genre».I know how to do that with normal tables in a single query:

```
SELECT *
FROM work a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(f_a.id SEPARATOR '|') AS genre_id, GROUP_CONCAT(f_a.genre SEPARATOR '|') AS genre_name, f_b.work_id AS _work_id
    FROM genre f_a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM work_has_genre f_b_a
    ) f_b
    ON f_a.id=f_b.genre_id
    GROUP BY f_b.work_id
) f
ON a.id=f._work_id
WHERE a.id=13
```

I suppose the idea would be to break this actions in parts, but I don't know how. Could someone help me with a bit of pseudocode? Or maybe this is not the best approach. Any idea will be very welcomed!

A.

Comment: First thoughts: You could get rid of the unnecessary subqueries (some might be, but a few are obviously not).  Example: While the aggregation in `c` and `d` may require them to be subqueries, it doesn't require them to have subqueries of their own.

Comment: You are in reason, I can clean that query a lot… I didn't realize that until now. But it will be slow still, and if I could break that in parts it would be great.

Comment: As you streamline the subqueries, you may find you can merge some completely into the main query, and reduce duplicate references to some tables (such as `work_has_edition`) with careful use of `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`, `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`, etc... Of course this is no guarantee you will get much in the way of speed improvements; depending on the structure of your data it may even have worse performance.

Comment: Yes, with so much data the improvements with subqueries are very small. That is why I was thinking in a different approach with remporary tables...

Comment: 30,000 rows is not a lot of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments, I would first suggest reworking/flattening the subqueries as much as possible first, but once you get to semi-independent aggregations temp tables can be helpful.

Generally, the pattern is to put each such aggregation subquery's results into it's own temp table (with an index on the field the subquery was joined to the main query on) even if that means adding tables (and the main query's WHERE) to the original subquery, and then joining to the temp table in the main query.

Comment: So the way would be first, to flatten my query; then, break it into parts and put them into different temporary tables. And then you JOIN the temporary tables at the end to output all the data. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. Each subquery can usually be executed faster, and then it's results stored in an indexed temp table for quick joining in the final query. Of course direct table joins are almost always faster than subqueries (or putting separate queries' results into temp tables first), but sometimes it is not reasonably possible (such as with these kinds of aggregation mixes).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! In fact, I am flattening the main query, and I can make almost all the concats in the main select. But anyway, after flattening it, I will break it in temporary tables.